# How do I write this ruby class?

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to write a class to store bans. I want to check if a given IP is banned and return `@ip`, `@time`, `@reason` etc.:

```
class BannedIP
  attr_reader :ip, :time, :reason
  def initialize(ip, time, reason)
    @ip = ip
    @time = time
    @reason = reason
  end
  def banned?(ip)
    # What do I use here?
  end
end
```

I need help with the part `# What do I use here?` so that I can do something like:

```
if b = BannedIP.banned? '10.10.10.10'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure returning `ip` when you already know `ip` makes sense but anyhoo...

You could use a custom hash class:

```
class BannedHash < Hash

  def ban(ip, time, reason)
      self[ip] = {time: time, reason: reason}
  end

  def banned?(ip)
      if self.include?(ip)
        self[ip]
      else
       "ip: #{ip} not found."
    end
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
def main
    b = BannedHash.new
    b.ban("10.10.10.10", Time.now, "Some reason")
    puts b.banned?("10.10.10.10")
    puts b.banned?("11.11.11.11")
end
```

Output:

```
{:time=>2015-04-27 21:18:39 +1200, :reason=>"Some reason"}
ip: 11.11.11.11 not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql2 and active record gems

```
gem install mysql2
gem install active_record
```

Then execute following code snapshot

```
require 'active_record'
require 'mysql2'

SOURCE_CREDNTIALS =  {
    :adapter  => "mysql2",
    :host     => "localhost",
    :username => "root",
    :password => "password",
    :database => "banned_db"
}

class Banned < ActiveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(SOURCE_CREDNTIALS)

  #attr_accessor :id, :ip, :banned_at, :reason

  def self.banned?(ip)
    where(ip: ip).count > 0
  end

end
```

Now you can use this simple class as

```
user_foo = Banned.create(ip: '10.10.10.10', banned_at: Time.now, reason: 'violated terms and conditions')
Banned.banned?('10.10.10.10')
```

BannedIP.banned? method would return true or false depending upon if particular ip is banned or not.

Comment: It is not required. Sorry i did forget to remove that.

Comment: This works, but I find it a bit hackish. Also, when you drop references to a `BannedIP` object, it will remain banned until it's garbage-collected. Not sure if this is intended.

Comment: Garbage collector will not destroy object if code is executing and objects are in scope. But in case you restart system or something else, you need to persist data on database or file system. Try using active_record gem to connect with database and map objects with rows in database table.

Comment: The garbage collector **does** remove objects that are not referenced anymore. This has nothing to do with scope. Just try it, please: `BannedIP.new('10.10.10.10', Time.now, 'xyz'); x = GC.count; y = []; y += y while GC.count == x; puts BannedIP.banned?('10.10.10.10')`

Comment: So best solution is to persist data on database. Install mysql and active_record gem and run updated code. Hope it would works fine.

Comment: Dont forget to create database and table named 'banneds' with columns id, ip, reason and banned_at

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a waste to have a full class for this unless you are planning on putting more in it. If it's just this then track it with an array, it would be easier and cost you less memory.

```
class BannedIP
  attr_accessor :ip, :time, :reason, :status

  def initialize(ip)
    @ip = ip
    @time = Time.new
    @reason = reason
    @status = status.nil? ? false : true
  end

  def ban(reason)
    @reason = reason
    @time = Time.new
    @status = true
  end
  def unban
    @reason = ""
    @time = Time.new
    @status = false
  end
  def banned?
      return @status
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "ban the bad guy at 10.0.0.1 because he was cheating"
  a = BannedIP.new("10.0.0.1")
  a.ban "he is a cheater!!"
  puts "The status of 10.0.0.1 is " + a.status.to_s
end

$ ruby stack1.rb
ban the bad guy at 10.0.0.1 because he was cheating
The status of 10.0.0.1 is true
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to ban several IPs.